# Minimize Coupling by Extending/Inheriting a Set of Shared XML types with Additional Attributes

Tags: xml, oop, inheritance, xsd, encapsulation

I would like to decouple the concerns of two development teams who share a set of XML types. The shared types are defined in a shared XSD. However, the second team needs an additional group of attributes on most of the fields in the shared XML types that are only relevant to their set of requirements. Currently, these propriety attributes are embedded in most of the fields in the shared XSD.

I would like to isolate these attributes to a set of XML types that extend the shared XML types, just as you would do in a simple OO language. Ayesha Malik had some ideas that got me started, using techniques from [Building XML schemas in an object-oriented framework](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-flexschema/#ibm-pcon)

Thanks to [to add attributes ... to add facets](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F626319%2Fadd-attributes-to-a-simpletype-or-restrictrion-to-a-complextype-in-xml-schema&ei=4x0XUPS8Aufr6wHU3IBA&usg=AFQjCNHk51FSNu5Ilb1uWMFyuLBdylOEDA)  I was able to add attributes to the complexTypes of the individual fields. But when I attempt to override the types for the sub-elements in one of the complex, shared types, the validation in Eclipse complains that

> The particle type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the
>   base.

If I leave the individual sub-element types the same, it validates just great. But if I change their types to the new derived types, the validation fails.  It's frustrating, because the fact that the types of the individual sub-elements are different then the parent type is the whole point of the exercise. I want to add a group of attributes to just about every field / sub-element in the parent types, and I am not seeing any way to do it.

I isolated an example that demonstrates that you can add the attributes to both simpleType and complextType, with simpleContent.  But I am not able to add the attributes to a derived complexType with complextContent.  For example, in the complexType "SearchPamphlet" below, I have tried using both <xs:extension>, and <xs:restriction>.  I have also tried setting the 'base' to be "Book" and "Pamphlet".  All of these approaches produce the same error.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:complexType name="Book">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Author" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="ISBN" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Pamphlet">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="Book">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Author" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ISBN" type="PamphletISBN" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="ISBNType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="PamphletISBN">
        <xs:restriction base="ISBNType">
            <xs:maxLength value="5" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="SearchablePamphlet">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="Book">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="SearchableString" />
                    <xs:element name="Author" type="SearchableString" />
                    <xs:element name="ISBN" type="SearchablePamphletISBN" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SearchablePamphletISBN">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="PamphletISBN">
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="searchableAttributes" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SearchableString">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="searchableAttributes" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:attributeGroup name="searchableAttributes">
        <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer" />
    </xs:attributeGroup>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XSD below strictly matches the intent of the source you've posted. The main point is to make you understand how restriction works in XSD, and the overhead you need to consider in authoring.

To explain: instead of Book, which is already ***restricted***, you need to start with a "SearcheableBook", an entity that has all you need, and from it, you scale back through various restrictions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="SearchableBook" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title" type="SearchableString"/>
            <xs:element name="Author" type="SearchableString"/>
            <xs:element name="ISBN" type="SearchableString"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Book">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableBook">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="SimpleTitle"/>
                    <xs:element name="Author" type="SimpleAuthor"/>
                    <xs:element name="ISBN" type="SimpleISBN"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SimpleTitle">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableString">
                <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer" use="prohibited"/>              
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>     
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SimpleAuthor">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableString">
                <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer" use="prohibited"/>                              
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SimpleISBN">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableString">
                <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer" use="prohibited"/>                              
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Pamphlet">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableBook">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="SimpleTitle"/>
                    <xs:element name="Author" type="SimpleAuthor"/>
                    <xs:element name="ISBN" type="PamphletISBN"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PamphletISBN">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableString">
                <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
                <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>
                <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer" use="prohibited"/>                              
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SearchablePamphlet">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableBook">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="SearchableString"/>
                    <xs:element name="Author" type="SearchableString"/>
                    <xs:element name="ISBN" type="SearchablePamphletISBN"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="SearchablePamphletISBN">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="SearchableString">
                <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="SearchableString">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attributeGroup ref="searchableAttributes"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:attributeGroup name="searchableAttributes">
        <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

Also, I would try to think the model differently, with extensions, see if it can be done in a way I would call it cleaner (I've seen recently how a complex case of restrictions choke the most expensive XSD editor in the market...)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your response. It works syntactically. Unfortunately, the answer only works in the example scenario where there is only a **single** set of derived types. This doesn't scale in the situation where multiple development teams are working from a common library of shared types.

For instance, in the situation where there is a standard company library of shared types that contained the example types "**Book**", "**Pamphlet**" and "**PamphletISBN**", and the library XSD file was "*frozen*" by a standards process.

In that situation, the search team would not have any ability to modify the **Book** type, nor would you really want them to.  Because the other development teams have competing requirements. For example, the sales team would want to have attributes for "**lifeTimeSales**", "**topRanking**", "**highestRatings**", etc., while the production team may want to add attributes for "**monthlyPrinting**", "**numberInInventory**" etc.

---

Since yesterday, I have tried to solve this requirement using ***elements***. Unfortunately, that approach also doesn't scale beyond a single type level.

Another approach that I am going to investigate is using substitution groups and see if that opens up any avenues. I will post it if I find a solution.

Again, thank-you for your suggestion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "single set of derived types". In theory, one could restrict or extend as many times as needed as long as you start from the right base. As I was trying to show, to restrict (in XSD 1.0) it means you cast wider at the top, and you make it more specific as you "specialize", or at the bottom. There is a reason why one wants to build a hierarchy. In your case, if the base type is important, I could build a Book that supports anyAttribute, then the sales team will restrict that list to lifeTimeSales, etc., etc. Then, there's always xsd:redefine, etc.

Comment: (cont'd) I think that is all in how you formulate the problem, which starts with understanding the need of the type hierarchy and how is that relevant to the associated processing model of the XML. Substitution groups can work wonders.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that provides the isolation of concerns that I was after.
The solution is to use the "***Salami Slice***" design pattern, combined with **substitutionGroup**'s.

With an omniscient and prescient analyst, it may be possible for the base file to anticipate very developmental need, or if your company's standards committee is okay with changing the base-types XSD files every time a development group in the company comes up with yet another element or attribute that they want to add. But in the work experiences that I have had in my career I have never had the opportunity to work with such an individual, nor such a standards committee.

I have posted three XSD files that demonstrate the isolation of concerns below, along with a sample XML file. In the posted code, I am assuming that the BaseTypes.xsd file is frozen and under the control of a change-review board.  I am also assuming that the DerivedTypes.xsd, Products.xsd and Test.xml files would be produce by the local products development group:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- XMLInheritance_BaseDataTypes -->

    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance" xmlns:bk="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance"
      elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

      <xs:element name="Book" type="bk:BookType" />
      <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Author" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="ISBN" type="bk:ISBNType" />

      <xs:simpleType name="ISBNType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
      </xs:simpleType>

      <xs:complexType name="BookType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="bk:Title" />
          <xs:element ref="bk:Author" />
          <xs:element ref="bk:ISBN" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

    </xs:schema>


    ----------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- XMLInheritance_DerivedDataTypes -->

    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance" xmlns:bk="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance"
      elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

      <xs:include schemaLocation="XMLInheritance_BaseDataTypes.xsd" />

      <xs:element name="SearchableBook" type="bk:SearchableBookType"
        substitutionGroup="bk:Book" />
      <xs:element name=" SearchableTitle " type="bk:SearchableString"
        substitutionGroup="bk:Title" />
      <xs:element name="SearchableAuthor" type="bk:SearchableString"
        substitutionGroup="bk:Author" />
      <xs:element name="SearchableISBN" type="bk:SearchableISBNType"
        substitutionGroup="bk:ISBN" />

      <xs:attributeGroup name="searchableAttributes">
        <xs:attribute name="caseMatches" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:attribute name="spellingMatches" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:attribute name="checksum" type="xs:integer" />
      </xs:attributeGroup>

      <xs:complexType name="SearchableBookType">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:restriction base="bk:BookType">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="bk:SearchableTitle" />
              <xs:element ref="bk:SearchableAuthor" />
              <xs:element ref="bk:SearchableISBN" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="SearchableISBNType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="bk:ISBNType">
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="bk:searchableAttributes" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="SearchableString">
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="bk:searchableAttributes" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>

    </xs:schema>


    ----------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- XMLInheritance_DerivedProducts.xsd -->

    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance" xmlns:bk="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance"
      elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xs:include schemaLocation="XMLInheritance_DataTypes.xsd" />

      <xs:element name="Product">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="Books">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element name="Book" type="bk:BookType" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="SearchableBooks" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element name="SearchableBook" type="bk:SearchableBookType" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>


    ----------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- XMLInheritance_Test.xml -->
    <bk:Product xmlns:bk="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xs:schemaLocation="http://www.company.org/XMLInheritance XMLInheritance_DerivedProducts.xsd ">

      <bk:Books>
        <bk:Book>
          <bk:Title>Title</bk:Title>
          <bk:Author>Author</bk:Author>
          <bk:ISBN>ISBN</bk:ISBN>
        </bk:Book>
      </bk:Books>
      <bk:SearchableBooks>
        <bk:SearchableBook>
          <bk:SearchableTitle>Searchable Title</bk:SearchableTitle>
          <bk:SearchableAuthor>Searchable Author</bk:SearchableAuthor>
          <bk:SearchableISBN>Searchable ISBN</bk:SearchableISBN>
        </bk:SearchableBook>
      </bk:SearchableBooks>

    </bk:Product>
```